# Coherence with an infinfinite number of waves

Tags: waves, coherence

**If I had an infinite number of sine waves with frequencies between 0 and 2, and I know what amplitude each wave has, is there a way for me to predict how they interfere?**

**for example if I have:**

frequencies=[ 0 ......................... 2]

amplitudes=sin(frequencies*(pi/1))+sin(frequencies*(pi/2))

wave=sum(amplitudes*sin((pi*2)*frequencies))

**what would the wave's phase and amplitude be at any given point?**

**thanks.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that the amplitude function $A(\omega)$ has a known [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform), you can find the sum as
$A(t) = \operatorname{Re} \int\!d\omega\, A(\omega) e^{i \omega t}$
.
If the Fourier transform isn't known, you can [estimate it numerically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform).

Comment: Hi, I don't understand how to solve that. what do dω, and eiωt mean?

Comment: $\omega$ is the angular frequency $2\pi f$. I used complex numbers and [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) to write $\sin(\omega t)$ in a convenient way. The rest is an [integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral), which is a fancy way of writing a sum over frequencies $\omega$.

Comment: So to sum all frequencies between $\omega = 0$ and $\omega = 4\pi$, you would break the range up into intervals $\Delta \omega = \frac{4\pi}{N}$ and let $N \to \infty$. You would write your sum as $\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} (\Delta \omega) A(\omega) \sin (\omega t)$. The calculus way of writing that is simply $\int_0^{4\pi} \! d\omega\, A(\omega) \sin(\omega t) \,$.